# Simple interest tricky question

Tags: finance

> A man borrowed $500$ dollar from his friend and decided to return this
>   amount in four installments of $150$ dollar each at the end of $3$, $6$ and
>   $9$th month. Find the rate of simple interest p.a if the first
>   installment is given in the beginning.

Solution-

I have used Principal = 350 dollar as 150 dollar already paid and simple interest = 100 dollar

On solving using formula i get answer as 38% (app)

But actual answer given is 36.36%

I think something wrong in my solution. But dont know where. Please help me to solve.

Comment: You can use `$500\$$` for the result $500\$$. Note (no pun intended) however that the dollar sign comes before the number: $\$500$

Comment: Ok thank you for your help. Please help me with this question also.